# Supremum and infimum of closed sets in the order topology

Tags: general-topology, analysis, order-theory, supremum-and-infimum

Let $\ge$ be a total order on a connected set $X$. If $A \subseteq X$ is closed in the order topology, then $\sup{A}$ and $\inf{A}$ belong to $A$.

My proof:
Suppose $\text{sup}A \notin A$. Then $\text{sup}A \in X\backslash A$, which is open. By definition, there exists a base element $(a,b)$ such that 
$$ \text{sup}A \in (a,b) \subseteq X\backslash A.$$
By the linear continuum properties (satisfied as long as $X$ is connected) , $\sup{A}$ exists and there is an element $a^{\star}$ such that $a < a^{\star} <\sup{A}$, then $a^{\star} \in (a,b) \subseteq X\backslash A$, so $a^{\star}$ is an upper bound of $A$ smaller that $\text{sup}A$, reaching a contradiction.
The case of $\text{inf}A$ is specular.

I think that the only counterexamples here can be found in the cases $\sup{A}$ does not exist. For example, pick $\mathbb{N} \subset \mathbb{R}$ and $\sup{\mathbb{N}}$ is not in $\mathbb{N}$ as it does not exist here.
My question is: if I assume, in addition to the proposition I stated, that $\sup{A}$ exists or I assume for example that $A$ is bounded above (hence the existence of the supremum follows), is the proof correct? Is it correct also in the cases in which I do not assume boundedness?

Comment: Proposition is false.

Comment: Is it false because the supremum cannot exist, right? Like the example I provided? If we add nonemptiness and boundedness is the above proof correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let K be a not empty, bounded above, closed subset
of a connected linear order space S.
max K in K. 
Proof.
Since S is connected, s = sup K in S.
Show for all open (a,b) nhood s, exists x in (a,b) $\cap$ K.
Thus s in K, QED.

An order dual proof will prove the order dual theorem:
not empty, bounded below, closed subsets have a minimum in them.

Comment: You proved it directly and it is fine. Assuming my set $A$ is nonempty and bounded above, can I work by contradiction as I did above?

Comment: Why bother? @WilliamBlake